# xsd element with the same name

Tags: xsd

to make xsd for element with same names that only identifyed by attribute value example :-

```
<a>
  <b n="structure one">
    <c n="inner element 1"/>
    <c n="inner element 2"/>
    <c n="inner element 3"/>
  </b>
  <b n="structure two">
    <c n="inner element 1 for structure two"/>
    <c n="inner element 2 for structure two"/>
    <c n="inner element 3 for structure two"/>
  </b>
</a>
```

notice that from the XML i have to mention specific value that belong to the inner element same for structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your specific requirements are, but the following schema validates your document.  It says that the root element must be named `a`, and it can contain any number of `b` elements, which themselves contain any number of `c` elements.  The `b` and `c` elements must contain the attribute with the name `n`.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="b">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="c">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="n" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="n" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you want to constrain the attributes to a specific set of values, you can use a restriction.  This schema enumerates the possible values of the `n` attributes on the `b` and `c` elements:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="b" type="b"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="b">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="c">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="n" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="inner element 1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="inner element 2"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="inner element 3"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="inner element 1 for structure two"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="inner element 2 for structure two"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="inner element 3 for structure two"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>

    <xs:attribute name="n" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="structure one"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="structure two"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="structure three"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

You can also constrain the values of the attributes with a regex pattern, like this:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="b" type="b"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="b">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="c">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="n" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="^inner element [0-9]+.*$"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>

    <xs:attribute name="n" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="structure (one|two|three)"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```